# Referencing subclasses from superclasses in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have an abstract class *Person*. There is another class *Student* which extends *Person*. But the Student class has a member variable, say *college* of type *String*, which is not there in *Person* class.

We know that we can reference a subclass from a superclass, for example,

**Person p = new Student();**

Will the object p have the member *college*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do `p.college`. However, you can cast it to `Student` and in this case it will have:

```
((Student) p).college;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your sample, `Person` object **IS** a `Student` and hence will have the `college` member.

Since you cast the `Student` to a `Person`, any public routines or data not present in `Person` will be hidden by the <strike>cast</strike> *assignment* though.

Comment: The idea is correct, but he is assigning a subtype to a member variable of a supertype, that's not *casting*.